# Динамический контекст приложения Java JSF (путь в адресной строке)

Tags: java, url, jsf

Есть веб приложение myApp.war. 
Приложение подразумевает наличие у пользователей персонального профиля.

Пользователь получает доступ к редактированию своего профиля по адресу - myapp.com/userName/editProfile.xhtml

userName  из адреса соответствует логину пользователя который он указал при регистрации. Его userName соответственно храниться в базе и для каждого пользователя он будет свой, уникальный. За счет уникальности урлов и организована система доступа к данным при помощи filter.

Вопрос - как в JSF динамически создавать урл состоящий из userName?

Или, если перефразировать вопрос - у меня в проекте будет директория, в которой, среди прочих будет лежать страничка editProfile.xhtml но доступ к этой страничке возможен для каждого авторизованного пользователя только по своему контексту, который буден начинаться с myapp.com/userName/-

Как динамически создавать контекст приложения?

Структура приложения не обсуждается, пример не реальный, выдуман специально для формулирования вопроса.

Спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одно слово, точнее слово ссылка - [PrettyFaces](https://www.ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/)!

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/238451)

Comment: @elik, название библиотеки является ответом.